# UWP - Cross device communication

Tags: c#, visual-studio, network-programming, win-universal-app

I'm currently building an App (App 1) in UWP and I want it to communicate with an App on another device (App 2). When a user on 'App 2' is pressing a button, then the user on App 1 will be notified, and vice versa. How can can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some ways to solver your problem:

If your scenario is for local connection you can use 
Sockets
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets

If you need to send messages from App1 to App 2 over the internet you can use Push Notifications with Microsoft Azure ( you need a backend)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/

There is another way to send messages in almost real time

SignalR
http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Consuming-Server-Side-SignalR-Events-in-Universal-Windows-App-Clients.aspx

I hope this helps!